# Joining master and child with only the row count of child table

Tags: sql-server

Master Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[db_Chat](
    [ChatID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MemberID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MsgText] [nvarchar](300) COLLATE Chinese_Taiwan_Stroke_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_db_Chat] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ChatID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Child Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[db_Chat_Read](
    [ChatReadID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MemberID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChatID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_db_Chat_Read] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ChatReadID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to join the two tables and show the number of rows of child table, if there is no row selected then it can show zero.

I know the following code works fine.

```
select c.ChatID, COUNT(*) as ACount  from db_chat c
left join db_Chat_Read r
on c.ChatID = r.ChatID
where c.ChatGroupID=2
GROUP BY c.ChatID
```

But I need something like this in a single SQL code, the following SQL code is invalid, but it is to show what result I want: I need full fields of master table with only Row Count of child table.

```
select c.*, COUNT(r.*)  from db_chat c
left join db_Chat_Read r
on c.ChatID = r.ChatID
where c.ChatGroupID=2
```

Thank you~!

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want with a subquery:

```
select c.*,
       (select COUNT(*) from db_Chat_Read r where c.ChatID = r.ChatId
       ) as ACount
from db_chat c
where c.ChatGroupID = 2;
```

However, I would recommend putting the columns in the `group by`.

EDIT:

You can also do this with an additional `join`:

```
select c.*, coalesce(ACount, 0) as ACount
from db_chat c left join
     (select r.ChatId, count(*) as ACount
      from db_Chat_Read r
      group by r.ChatId
     ) r
    on c.ChatID = r.ChatID
where c.ChatGroupID = 2;
```

Comment: I prefer the first, but either are ok

Comment: If the amount of data is enormous, which one is more efficient? If I'm not wrong, the first one is more efficient?

Comment: @HamiltonWang . . . The first is probably more efficient, assuming that the `where` clause has high selectivity (meaning many rows are filtered out) and that all or almost all "chats" have "chat read" records.  It would be even more efficient with an index on `db_Chat_Read(ChadId)`.